# Multi-level storage in tdengine database

Tags: tdengine

I am using TDengine enterprise trial version, I know it supports Multi-level storage, but when I set dataDir in taos.cfg file like below, it didn't work.

```
dataDir /var/lib/taos/data1
dataDir /var/lib/taos/data2
```

the data will be stored in second directory. What is the correct configuration to make  Multi-level storage work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like below:

- dataDir [path] level primary

level: at most 3 levels allowed, each level can mount 16 paths
primary: 0 or 1, 1 means primary mount point, each level has at most 1 primary mount point

example:

dataDir /mnt/data1 0 1
dataDir /mnt/data2 0 0
dataDir /mnt/data3 0 0
dataDir /mnt/data4 1 1
dataDir /mnt/data5 1 0
dataDir /mnt/data6 1 0